# ASP.NET MVC, strongly typed view; on edit/update of an item should I map properties or attach object to session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to grasp DDD here, and I've read somewhere that it is *possible* to reuse the domain entities as viewmodels. I've created a simple CRUD app, but at the U(pdate), I get a bit stuck at "?????":

```
// snippet of the content of the ItemController:
public ViewResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    Item item = _itemDomainService.GetFromCurrentUser(id);
    return View(item);
}

[HttpPost]
[Transaction]
public ViewResult Edit(Item item)
{
    // Validate here

    //????
    return Redirect("Item", "Details", item.Id);
}
```

I'm using nhibernate with the session per request pattern ("Transaction" is a custom attribute). But "item" is not "tracked" (it is *transient*) to the nhibernate session. What is the preferred method of getting the changes in "item"  into the corresponding row in the database?

I'm thinking of the folowing options myself:

- Map all properties to the persistent "item", so (at the "????"):

  ```
  var fromDB = _itemDomainService.GetById(item.Id);
  fromDB.Name = item.Name;
  fromDB.Description = item.Description
  // etc
  ```
- Attach the item to session:

  ```
   // of course session would be abstracted away, but for brevity pretend it gets injected into the controller
   session.Update(item);
  ```
- My design is plain wrong, and I need to (for example) not use the session-per request...

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, tricky because I know MVC but not NHibernate. I do know Entity Framework though so I'll assume they are similar enough for this to still be useful I hope:

I would do something like:

```
//get the original item from the DB
var fromDB = _itemDomainService.GetById(item.Id);

//update fromDB with values from the current "Item" that was posted
UpdateModel(fromDB);

//then save the changes that were made
_itemDomainService.SaveChanges();
//this last line is how it is done in Entity Framework - but I guess there is something similar in NHibernate
```

Comment: Never saw UpdateModel(). That does seem like a nifty method! NHibernate will track the changes for me so I don't even have to call .SaveChanges(). This might just be what I was looking for.

Comment: cool. Just so you know Entity Framework tracks changes too but you need to call savechanges makes it actually commit those changes to the database

Answer (score 3):

It is generally considered better form to pass a DTO (Data Transfer Object) between the controller and the view, rather than your domain entities themselves.

Then, in your Edit action in your controller, you retrieve the object from your repository using the Id provided by the DTO, and update the properties, essentially like you suggest above.

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
[Transaction]
public ViewResult Edit(ItemDTO item)
{
    // Validate here

    var fromDB = _itemDomainService.GetById(item.Id);
    fromDB.Name = item.Name;
    fromDB.Description = item.Description
    return Redirect("Item", "Details", item.Id);
}
```

To avoid writing lots of 'fromDB.X = item.X' code, you should have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) which will map the properties for you if your name your DTO properties according to some simple conventions.

Comment: I agree that using a DTO is way better than using your regular Entity in most cases. You could also recieve each and every Property as regular arguments to the Action, but it will clutter your Action-signature.

Comment: When would a DTO instead of the domain entity benefit me? Since in this situation I don't see it.

Comment: My previous comment is a genuine question, not rethorical. I'd really like to know why "using a DTO is way better".

Comment: For very simple scenarios, you may be able to get away with just using the entity. But eventually you will find that some views require display only properties that don't make sense being part of your domain entity, or you may find that your domain entities have properties you don't want to pass to your view, especially when you have nested properties.

Comment: Since I think my current project satisfies as a "simple scenario", I'll keep using just the entity. I'll keep this in mind for bigger projects though. Also, I didn't know about AutoMapper, very interesting!

Comment: in that case, I'd still recommend retrieving an instance of the item you want to update, updating it's properties, and then saving it.

Comment: @Mr Happy - If you can 'get by' with entities - DO! There is no sense in writing more code with no good reason - use the framework that you have been blessed with! I have used DTOs before in a WCF service that required serialization of complex navigation properties but other than that I haven't used DTOs in 1.5yrs of MVC development. By the way this is just a subjective counter argument for Mr Happy's benefit. Nobody is wrong

Comment: Oh I just realised what you're all going on about. Entity Framework creates partial classes so I can extend them how I feel. I still feel you shouldn't use them if you don't *need* to though as wholeheartedly subscribe to the KISS way of developing